# Why is inserting into a set<vector<string>> so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, set

For a class project we are making a simple compiler / Relational Database. Mine produces the correct answers, but too slowly on large queries. I ran visual studio's performance analysis and my program is spending 80% of it's time inserting my tuples (rows in a table) into a set. The function is part of computing a cross product, so the result has lots and lots of rows, but I need suggestions on a faster way to insert my tuples into the set.

```
for (set<vector<string>>::iterator it = tuples.begin(); it != tuples.end(); ++it)
{
    for (set<vector<string>>::iterator it2 = tuples2.begin(); it2 != tuples2.end(); ++it2)
    {
        vector<string> f(*it);
        f.insert(f.end(), it2->begin(), it2->end());
        newTuples.insert(f); //This is the line that takes all the processing time
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `newTuples`?

Comment: Your vector is created by copy at each insert. Use pointers and new.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, what a terrible suggestion...

Comment: @SergeyA: didn't know about std::move, ty.

Comment: newTuples are all the rows that are going into the new table I am making.

Comment: If you need performance from Visual Studio containers, *do* use the Release mode. The Debug mode with its checked iterators is really great for finding errors, but there are many use cases where the performance drops below any useful level.

Answer (score 4):

You are copying big vector by value for no reason. You should move: `newTuples.insert(std::move(f));`

Comment: Makes sense, but had no effect on how long the function was taking. The vectors aren't very big (20 items max)

Answer (score 1):

A `set` might be the wrong container. A `set` is ordered, and keeps only unique elements. There might be many `string` comparisons happening when you insert a new `vector`.

Use a `list` or a `vector` instead (if you can).

<sup>...and avoid needless copying, as SergeyA already pointed out in his answer</sup>

Comment: You're probably right, I used a set originally as an easy way to get rid of duplicates. Changing it now would require a lot of refactoring and probably isn't worth the 1% of my grade.

Answer (score 0):

We might as well go C++11 (totally untested code)

```
for (const auto& it : tuples) {
    for (const auto& it2 : tuples2) {
        auto where = newTuples.emplace(it); // returns where its placed
        auto& vect = where.first; // makes the next more readable
        vect.insert(vect.end(), it2.begin(), it2.end());
    }
}
```

Note on collisions some strings disappears from the result, is that really what you want?
Your using the vector as key, will that ever be a collision? add

```
if (!where.second) {
  ; // collision
}
```

to check.

This should remove all double work of moving (if the compiler doesn't optimize it away anyway).